# dynamic update of bokeh image

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter/notebooks or jupyter/lab.

I would like to change image content displayed by bokeh in a dynamical fashion - either on a button click , combobox change or upon a background thread change. Although it was easy to change content for 1D graphs, as shown in example notebooks, I am stuck at changing the content of 2D image produced by bokeh. I would appreciate any help to make it work.

Here is the simplest code.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, TextInput

def simple_app(doc):
    
    p = figure(tools="", toolbar_location=None)
    
    p = figure(tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])
    p.x_range.range_padding = p.y_range.range_padding = 0
    
    r = p.image(image=[np.zeros((200,200))], x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10, palette="Spectral11", level="image")
    
    select = Select(title="Select data", value="file2", options=['file1','file2'])
    
    def update_data(attrname, old, new):
        tdata = {"file1": np.random.rand(200,200)*3,
                 "file2": np.random.rand(200,200)*5.,
                }
        # reading files        
        cd = ColumnDataSource(data={'image': tdata[select.value]})
        print(f"Selected {select.value}")

        r.data_source = cd # here it potentially could be changed, but does not seem to work
    
    select.on_change('value', update_data)

    layout = column(row(select, width=200), row(p))

    doc.add_root(layout)

show(simple_app)
```

Comment: Python callbacks require bokeh server, which will not work in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: In reality they do. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html). I reached some progress by updating layout - removing and adding a row with a new figure. But this is not the same as using the same figure and replacing the data shown.

Comment: I did miss `push_notebook()`, thanks.